# how to fetch field values from database and set in dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am new in **CodeIgniter** and working on a application in which i have a form. In this form I have a dropdown. I have some values in a column of database. I want these values in the dropdown, I have no idea how to do it.

My view is:

```
<tr>
    <td>Moderator :</td>
    <td><label for="select"></label>
    <select name="mod" tabindex="1" >
    <!--values i want from database-->
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you know how to fetch data with a model and pass that data to your view?

Comment: yeh i know . . @FabioAntunes

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to create a model to allow you to extract the data you need from the database.  It sounds like you don't know anything about MVC so I would suggest studying this first.

Comment: @Pattle :- i know about MVC i already create a model and fetch data from database but there is a problem with dropdown list . .

Comment: @Pattle:- let me explain . . i have one field named member_name i want to use it as moderator_name also..i give a dropdown in which i want to set this name and by selecting this new members created . .

Comment: @Jay Sorry, just that your question was a bit vague, you hadn't really explained what you had done so far so I assumed you weren't sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is for a country table in our application, the table contains, id, symbol, name

Controller:

```
$data['countries']=$this->countries_model->get_countries();
$this->load->view('countries',$data);
```

Model:

```
    function get_countries()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('countries');
            if ($query->num_rows >= 1)
            {
                foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row['countryId']]=$row['countryName'];
                }
                return $data;
            }
    }
```

It returns an array like:

```
$id=>$name
0=>Canada
1=>United States
```

View:

```
echo form_dropdown('countries',$countries); //ci syntax
```

Or:

```
<select name="country">
<?php
    foreach($countries as $country)
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$country['id'].'">'.$country['name'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Member_model extends CI_Model{

var $table = 'tbl_member';

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_all_members(){
    $this->db->from('tbl_member');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_by_id($id){
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('member_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}

public function member_add($data){
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function member_update($where, $data){
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}

public function delete_by_id($id){
    $this->db->where('member_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it? For example, how does it populate the select field that was asked for in the question?